# How do you convert between raw values and decimal (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I'm attempting to convert between various bases and raw in Python. I figured the easiest way would be to take as value in any base, convert it to decimal and then convert it to the desired output. For example: 'hex -> dec -> raw'

Input:

```
6e447a386c255b3b71306f6a537c4a3067414d5f724d426b513c652e23277077732c6c653747225c7c79497a475a6a3c78294170477a3f497a722b2d3e447326
```

Desired output:

```
nDz8l%[;q0ojS|J0gAM_rMBkQ<e.#'pws,le7G"\|yIzGZj<x)ApGz?Izr+->Ds&
```

The output was generated using [Cyberchef's from hex function](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex('Auto')&input=NmU0NDdhMzg2YzI1NWIzYjcxMzA2ZjZhNTM3YzRhMzA2NzQxNGQ1ZjcyNGQ0MjZiNTEzYzY1MmUyMzI3NzA3NzczMmM2YzY1Mzc0NzIyNWM3Yzc5NDk3YTQ3NWE2YTNjNzgyOTQxNzA0NzdhM2Y0OTdhNzIyYjJkM2U0NDczMjY).

I'm currently stuck on how to convert both to raw and from a raw UTF-8 encoded string to a decimal value.

Comment: what is you trying to achieve and what have you  tried so far?

Comment: RAW is not a base, but rather an image format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode a byte object created by fromhex and get your desired result.

```
def hex_to_str(hex):
    return bytes.fromhex(hex).decode('utf-8')

hex_to_str("6e447a386c255b3b71306f6a537c4a3067414d5f724d426b513c6
52e23277077732c6c653747225c7c79497a475a6a3c78294170477a3f497a722b2d3e447326")
```

Result:

`>>> nDz8l%[;q0ojS|J0gAM_rMBkQ<e.#'pws,le7G"\|yIzGZj<x)ApGz?Izr+->Ds&`

Comment: Thank you, I'm guessing their is something similar for other bases such as dec,oct,b64?. How would you do the inverse of this, raw to hex?

Comment: @Cyreaver for dec use `int(text, 16)` for oct use `oct(int)` and for bs64 first `from base64 import b64encode` then `b64encode(text.encode())` and for reverse function `hex(text)` works fine.

Comment: Oh okay so its easier if I convert from any base to hex first and then to the desired output? Thank you.